# Angularjs Byte Array to Blob

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I am trying to view a PDF saved in binary data in our SQL database using Angular and PDF.js.  The data returned from the service looks like this:

[image]

Essentially, I believe that I need to create an objectURL for it to work, but I'm not sure how to convert it to a blob.  I have tried the following:

```
        .success(function (response) {
        var fileName = response[0].FileName;
        var fileImage = response[0].binFileImage;
        var blob = new Blob(fileImage, { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I use the following to convert image files:

```
 function base64ArrayBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
    var base64 = ''
    var encodings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

    var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    var byteLength = bytes.byteLength
    var byteRemainder = byteLength % 3
    var mainLength = byteLength - byteRemainder

    var a, b, c, d
    var chunk

    // Main loop deals with bytes in chunks of 3
    for (var i = 0; i < mainLength; i = i + 3) {
        // Combine the three bytes into a single integer
        chunk = (bytes[i] << 16) | (bytes[i + 1] << 8) | bytes[i + 2]

        // Use bitmasks to extract 6-bit segments from the triplet
        a = (chunk & 16515072) >> 18 // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18
        b = (chunk & 258048) >> 12 // 258048   = (2^6 - 1) << 12
        c = (chunk & 4032) >> 6 // 4032     = (2^6 - 1) << 6
        d = chunk & 63               // 63       = 2^6 - 1

        // Convert the raw binary segments to the appropriate ASCII encoding
        base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + encodings[d]
    }

    // Deal with the remaining bytes and padding
    if (byteRemainder == 1) {
        chunk = bytes[mainLength]

        a = (chunk & 252) >> 2 // 252 = (2^6 - 1) << 2

        // Set the 4 least significant bits to zero
        b = (chunk & 3) << 4 // 3   = 2^2 - 1

        base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + '=='
    } else if (byteRemainder == 2) {
        chunk = (bytes[mainLength] << 8) | bytes[mainLength + 1]

        a = (chunk & 64512) >> 10 // 64512 = (2^6 - 1) << 10
        b = (chunk & 1008) >> 4 // 1008  = (2^6 - 1) << 4

        // Set the 2 least significant bits to zero
        c = (chunk & 15) << 2 // 15    = 2^4 - 1

        base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + '='
    }

    return base64
}
```

I tried using it for the PDF, but I'm not sure if that is the correct format.  The above function converts the byte array to:

```
JVBERi0xLjQNCiX5+prnDQo3IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL0UgMzU0ODENCi9IIFsgMTM3OCAxNjMgXQ0KL0wgMzc3NzkNCi9MaW5lYXJpemVkIDENCi9OIDINCi9PIDEwDQovVCAzNzU4OQ0KPj4gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICANCmVuZG9iag0KDQp4cmVmDQo3IDExDQowMDAwMDAwMDE3IDAwMDAwIG4NCjAwMDAwMDEyN... (shortened).
```

I'm not really sure what I need to do to convert the data so that I can use it to create an object url so that I can view the pdf.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For Blob you need array of arrays, e.g. `var blob = new Blob([fileImage], { type: 'application/pdf' });`. Also pdf.js can consume binary data array as input too.

Comment: I tried that it throws an InvalidStateError.  It seems fileImage must be converted to something else first, but I don't know what or how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do this, but this works in IE and Chrome.

1. First, I converted the byte array to base64.
2. Next I converted the base64 to a Uint8Array.
3. Then I display the file.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
    lwsService.getdocument(id)
    .success(function (response) {
       var byteArray = new Uint8Array(response[0].binFileImage);
       var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
        } else {
          var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          window.open(objectUrl);
        }
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: can you just do `new Uint8Array(response[0].binFileImage)` ?

Comment: For me, the current answer didn't work, but the edited one (with all the arrays) helped me a lot.Thanks !

Comment: What data type is 'response[0].binFileImage' ?

Comment: @SomeRandomDeveloper - its a BLOB from SQL database

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example. it's using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

```
var blob = new Blob([content], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
saveAs(blob, "yourFile.pdf");
```

Comment: I'm not trying to save the file.  I'm trying to view it.